# Make [kusto-query-langauge] and [kql] tags synonyms and [azure-data-explorer] and [kusto] synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

[kql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kql) is an acronym for [kusto-query-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto-query-language), as described in its [tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kql). **[Please cast your vote on the suggested synonym.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kql)**

[kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto) is the database and [kql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kql) is the query language. [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto) was the name of that project, as long as it was Microsoft internal. Once it got out, the name was changed. [azure-data-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-explorer) was the chosen name. For example you can still see that under the azure-data-explorer documentation [there are many mentions of Kusto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data), which should probably get fixed. As another evidence you can see that the [python client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python) of [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto) directs asking questions under the azure-data-explorer tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Tomer Shetah's hand-holding to fill in my gaps in knowledge on the subject matter, the following changes have been made:

- [kql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kql) ← [kusto-query-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto-query-language)

  Since KQL is just the abbreviation of Kusto Query Language. For now, we've chosen to keep KQL as the "main" tag, and the long-form version as the synonym, but this can be easily reversed if ambiguity arises and/or someone makes an argument for why the long-form version should be the canonical.

- [azure-data-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-explorer) ← [azure-kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-kusto)
- [azure-data-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-explorer) ← [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto)

  Since "Kusto" was the development code-name of Azure Data Explorer, these are obvious synonyms. (For [azure-kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-kusto) in particular, it was only being used on 6 questions, and all 6 already had both the [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) and [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto) tags.) Azure Data Explorer is kept as the "main" tag, since that's the final, public name of the product.