# Tag synonyms are not reflected in the Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, developer-story, tag-synonym-process

Lately I started maintaining my developer story. I added there my previous role which was developing [azure-data-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-explorer). Its internal name was [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto). So I added  [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto) as a tag to this role.

Once I gained enough rep, I asked to [Make [kusto-query-langauge] and [kql] tags synonyms and [azure-data-explorer] and [kusto] synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404495/2359227), which was successfully done, but the [kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kusto) tag is still present in my Developer Story, instead of [azure-data-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-explorer).

My [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2359227).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags listed for your job history and some other places in your developer story **are not tied to tags on the site in any way**. You can type whatever you want there and it will be formatted as a tag, with the suggestions being populated from the existing tags list for convenience of typing things more quickly. That is also why they are *only* formatted to look like tags there and not directly linked to corresponding tags on the site.

We consider it entirely up to the developer to use tags they feel are relevant to their experience, whether they exist on the site or not. That includes updating them to new names if that is relevant to their job. But us automatically making that switch can have unintended side effects and cause confusion among developers who may not even be aware of an alternate name for something.

As an example, I used many Macromedia programs many years ago before they were bought out by Adobe. It would be appropriate to say I have experience with products that were Macromedia, because that is when I used them, but not Adobe products, because I have not used many of the Adobe versions.

Because the tags in your story are not tied to actual tags, but rather are meant to be freeform "enter whatever you want as a tag" boxes, we will not make automatic changes to them.